# Typo3 Error: The ColumnMap for property is missing

Tags: extbase, typo3-extensions

I'm using Typo3 version 8.7.8 and I'm developing an extention.
The two tables "auftrag" and "verstorbener" are connectet with a 1:n relation.
I try to search for a field in the table "verstorbener" in the repository of "auftrag". The relation of both is necessary.

If I try to execute the following query I get the error *"The ColumnMap for property "verstorbener" of class "...\Auftrag" is missing."*

```html
$name = "Mustermann";
  
$query->matching(
   $query->logicalAnd(
      $query->equals('verstorbener.nachname', $name)
   )
  );
```

How can I solve this problem?
If you need more input feel free to ask for it.

**Edit -- The relevant TCA code of the field "verst_id" in "auftrag" which contains the UID of "verstorbener":**

```
    'verst_id' => [
        'exclude' => true,
        'label' => 'LLL:EXT:.../locallang_db.xlf:auftrag.verst_id',
        'config' => [
            'type' => 'inline',
            'foreign_table' => 'verstorbener',
            'foreign_field' => 'uid',
            'minitems' => 0,
            'maxitems' => 1,
            'appearance' => [
                'collapseAll' => 0,
                'levelLinksPosition' => 'top',
                'showSynchronizationLink' => 1,
                'showPossibleLocalizationRecords' => 1,
                'showAllLocalizationLink' => 1
            ],
        ],
    ],
```

**Edit -- This is the object model**

```
/**
 * verstId
 *
 * @var \...\Domain\Model\Verstorbener
 */
protected $verstId = null;

/**
 * Returns the verstId
 *
 * @return \...\Domain\Model\Verstorbener $verstId
 */
public function getVerstId()
{
    return $this->verstId;
}

/**
 * Sets the verstId
 *
 * @param \...\Domain\Model\Verstorbener $verstId
 * @return void
 */
public function setVerstId(\...\Domain\Model\Verstorbener $verstId)
{
    $this->verstId = $verstId;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a field 'verstorbener' in your table 'auftrag', and TCA configuration? Ensure, that you can add entries from table 'verstorbener' to your table 'auftrag' in backend. Then please post your TCA snippet, as we can see, how your fields are named.

Comment: I have a field with the name "verst_id" which contains the uid from the table "verstorbener".

Comment: Then you should use "$query->equals('verst_id.nachname', $name)" in your Classes/Domain/Repository/AuftragRepository

Comment: It seems I'm getting the same error:

The ColumnMap for property "verst_id" of class "...\Domain\Model\Auftrag" is missing.

Comment: Because there is no $verstId in the model

Comment: There is a verstId in the model. 
I've postet the codelines I'd written to include verstId.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem.
It seems like there layd some old data in the Typo3 cache.
Clearing cache in the backend or in the installer doesn't helped.
I had uninstall and reinstall the extension by hand.

Comment: I have the same issue (but with m:n) but uninstalling and reinstalling hasn't solved the problem. Was there anything else you did?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue when I was upgrading an Extension from Typo3 v6 to Typo3 v8. The mechanism for including TCA config files has changed, so the Files in `/Configuration/TCA/` need to be named according to the extension name. For example: `tx_extension_domain_model_auftrag.php` 
The TCA configuration file only consists of a return array, no more `$TCA['tx_extension_domain_model_auftrag']`!

If you have TCA `ctrl` configuration in your `ext_tables.php` then combine this into the corresponding TCA files and remove the `dynamicConfigFile` definition!

Hope that helps :)